# Extract multiple numeric values from string in Python or Excel

Tags: excel, vba, information-extraction

I have a string that goes like this:

```
Adjustment-05/15/2019-2,000-Random text-Adjustment-05/16/2019-203.57
```

I just need to extract 2000 and put it in one column and 203.57 in another column. Potentially there could be more than two of these values.

Appreciate any help at all!

I tried in Excel to remove dates and text that worked but then I still have 2 values that I don't know how to separate. I tried the following two functions that work well but still I can't extract second or third numerical values.

```
Public Function ExtractNumber(inValue As String) As Double
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "(\d{1,3},?)+(\.\d{2})?"
        .Global = True
        If .Test(inValue) Then
            ExtractNumber = CDbl(.Execute(inValue)(0))
        End If
    End With
End Function

Function RemoveDates(MyRange As Range) As String
    Dim sRaw As String
    Dim sPattern As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp

    sRaw = MyRange.Value

    sPattern = "[0-9]{1,2}[-.\\/][0-9]{1,2}[-.\\/][0-9]{4}"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = sPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(sRaw) Then
        RemoveDates = regEx.Replace(sRaw, "")
    Else
        RemoveDates = "Not matched"
    End If
    Set regEx = Nothing
End Function
```

Result that I am looking for is 2000 in one column and 203.57 in another.

Comment: What is the potential range of values for the numbers? And are they always bracketed by hyphens? Is it possible that the "random text" will also have numerical digits or hyphens?

Comment: Can you give some more examples of input? Is it *always* formatted that exact same way, or can some parts be missing/longer/etc?

Comment: They will always be bracketed by hyphens. Range of numbers is from 1-100,000. Random text will never have numbers but can potentially have hyphens. Thank you!

Comment: Values that I need to extract will always have a format X,XXX.00 if that helps. I was originally thinking if there is a way to find number based on its format and extract it.

Comment: Number I need will also always follow a date! So no matter what other text might be, what I need will always look like: 01/01/2019-Amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will return an array of numeric values that follow a date in your string.

- It assumes the preceding data is always in the format of `nn/nn/nnnn-`, as you show in your single example.
- It also assumes there will never be another instance of `nn/nn/nnnn-` that is not a date.
- The value following the date is placed in a capturing group.
- It will return as many of these values as exist in the string.

You can either enter as an array across `n` columns, or use the `INDEX` function to return each value separately:

```
Option Explicit
Function ExtractNums(S As String) As Double()
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim D() As Double, I As Long
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}-([\d,.]+)"
    .Global = True
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ReDim D(1 To MC.Count)
        I = 0

        For Each M In MC
            I = I + 1
            D(I) = M.submatches(0)
        Next M
    End If
End With
ExtractNums = D

End Function
```

[image]